# Combined NFS, Samba server w users from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, samba, nfs, user-management

I want to build a server that exports user home directories over SMB/CIFS and NFS. This server would be joined to a Win2k3 AD domain controller that holds our user database. As I understand it, winbind will invent UIDs for these users on the fly. This username-UID mapping needs to be available to NFS clients that mount the home directories or file ownership will not be presented correctly.

I assume this can be achieved using SFU, but as far as I can tell SFU is discontinued and will not be supported on recent versions of Windows, so I would prefer not to use it.

How do I best provide this mapping to NFS clients?

(You would think this a common use case, but I fail to find a relevant howto. My Google-fu may be weak.)

EDIT: As an aside, would it be possible in this scenario for a user to connect over NFS without first having connected via SMB/CIFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Edit for 2017-07-05) I'd generally recommend using sssd now. Leaving the original answer below for historical reference. My current notes for Ubuntu are:

```
apt-get install openssh-server sssd-ad realmd packagekit
realm -v join example.com --computer-ou="OU=someOU,DC=example,DC=com" --user=someuser
```

- In `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`, `[sssd]` section, add `default_domain_suffix = example.com` and `full_name_format = %1$s`. In the `[domain/example.com]` section, edit `fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u` and add `ignore_group_members = True`. For larger domains, add `enumerate = false` to prevent sssd from traversing all over AD looking for group memberships (and delaying non-cached logins for a minute or two each).
- Append `session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0076` at end of `/etc/pam.d/common-session`. (or whatever umask you want to use).
- Restart `sssd` service with `service sssd restart`.
- Try logging in on a second text or GUI console, or with `ssh localhost`.

---

`winbind` would make up UIDs by default on older versions of Samba, or would have to refer to an LDAP store to keep everything consistent. That hasn't been the case for some time now (November 2004, if my information is correct) -- `idmap_rid` is a backend that can generate UIDs from the Active Directory RID (relative identifiter, part of the user's SID).

[I wrote up my configuration for tying Debian systems into an existing AD here](http://blogs.cae.tntech.edu/mwr/2007/08/02/authentication-servers-the-next-generation/) -- it uses Puppet, but if you only read through it for a starting point on Samba and PAM configurations, it should work on any comparable UNIX system.

Note that I'm not using SFU, or modifying the AD schema in any way. All I wanted was a consistent set of UIDs for my users.

Comment: This post got me on the right track. See below for a full dump of what I did.

Answer (score 2):

The NFS component of Services for Unix is now part of the **Services for Network File System** role in Server 2003 R2 and above.

There is a great Microsoft blog about SFU - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sfu/.  The relevant  blog entry explaining how to [set it up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sfu/archive/2008/12/15/set-up-services-for-network-file-system-in-windows-server-2008.aspx) and the definitive Technet article is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302%28WS.10%29.aspx).

You can use the Identity Management for UNIX Active Directory schema extension to do your mapping allowing NFS clients to connect to your server without having to CIFS first (if they could CIFS, doesn't make much sense to NFS?).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mike Renfro above, idmap_rid is the central component. Below is a list of shell commands that get a box up and running, given a fresh RHEL5.5 box:

client_packages:

```
yum -y install samba3x-winbind krb5-workstation nfs-utils portmap pam_krb5
chkconfig --add winbind
chkconfig winbind --level 345 on
chkconfig --add rpcidmapd
chkconfig rpcidmapd --level 345 on
chkconfig --add portmap
chkconfig portmap --level 345 on
chkconfig --add nfslock
chkconfig nfslock --level 345 on
```

client_setup:

```
umount /cpy/shared || true
umount /cpy/users || true

install samba-winbind.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
install krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
install idmapd.conf /etc/idmapd.conf

if ! net -S ad.example.com ads testjoin ; then
    net -S ad.example.com ads join -UAdministrator
fi

if ! grep -q winbind /etc/nsswitch.conf ; then
    sed -r  -e 's/^(passwd|shadow|group):.*$/& winbind/g' \
        -e 's/^hosts:.*$/& wins/g' -i /etc/nsswitch.conf
fi

( grep -v '172.18.0.2:' /etc/fstab && cat fstab.nfs-client ) \
    > /tmp/fstab.new && mv /tmp/fstab.new /etc/fstab

service winbind restart
service rpcidmapd restart
install -d /cpy/shared
install -d /cpy/users
mount -a
authconfig --enablewinbind --enablewinbindauth --enablekrb5 --update
echo "Make sure that /etc/hosts has an entry with .example.com"
```

samba-winbind.conf:

```
[global]
unix charset = LOCALE
workgroup = EXAMPLE
realm = example.com
security = ADS
log level = 2
syslog = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/%m
max log size = 50
idmap backend = idmap_rid:EXAMPLE=10000-20000
idmap uid = 10000-20000
idmap gid = 10000-20000
template shell = /bin/bash
template homedir = /cpy/users/%u
winbind separator = +
winbind cache time = 60
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind enum users = yes
winbind use default domain = yes
```

krb.conf:

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]

 default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = yes

[realms]
 PILOTFISH.SE = {
  kdc = ad.example.com
  admin_server = ad.example.com
  default_domain = example.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .pilotfish.se = EXAMPLE.COM
 pilotfish.se = EXAMPLE.COM

[appdefaults]
 pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
 }
```

idmapd.conf

```
[General]

Verbosity = 1
Pipefs-Directory = /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
Domain = example.com

[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nfsnobody
Nobody-Group = nfsnobody

[Translation]
Method = nsswitch
```

fstab.nfs-client

```
172.18.0.2:/users       /cpy/users              nfs4    defaults        0 0
172.18.0.2:/shared      /cpy/shared             nfs4    defaults        0 0
```