# Linux nfs4 permission problem with owner and group

Tags: linux, nfs

I have shared directory from NFS server, after mounting the particular directory in NFS client, the directory's user and group shows

```
drwxr-xr-x 20 nfsnobody nfsnobody 4096 Apr  5 04:30 webapps
```

I couldn't get the actual permission which I have in the NFS server. If i create any files or directories in NFS client the permission will be `nfsnobody nfsnobody`. Can anyone give me the suggestion to come out this problem because last 3 days i am struggling in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the permissions on the server? How is your server set up?

Comment: The server setup in /etc/exports = /home/sathish/ 192.168.10.10(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,async), The particular directory webapps contains the permission like drwxr-xr-x  8 sathish users  4096 Feb 22 16:22 webapps

Comment: It is not exactly related, but there may be some relevant info in my recent question on NFS: http://serverfault.com/questions/255373/combined-nfs-samba-server-w-users-from-active-directory. In particular, rpc.idpamd may be the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, go to the nfs server, and `ls -n` in the folder you are trying to access remotely.

Note that the user and group names are replaced with their actual id numbers.  Check on the client that these numbers match the user and group that own the folders in /etc/passwd and /etc/group.  Ie the group and user id numbers on both systems should be the same.  So if user1 has a uid of 1000 on the server, it should also have uid 1000 on the client.

If they do not, then you'll need to adjust your group and user ids so that they match on both systems.

If this is NFSv4 it can also be that you do not have idmapd running.  Check that /etc/idmapd.conf has an entry for "Domain" and they match on both client and server.  Make sure that idmapd is configured to start when nfs starts.  On debian style distros this is in /etc/default/nfs-common.   For Redhat based, it is in /etc/sysconfig/nfs.   Look for something along the lines of "NEED_IDMAPD"

Comment: If you add your distro to the question, the answer can become more specific